# Cannot connect to port 8080 when using the python module for Stanford NER

Tags: python

I am a complete rookie at this (this might be the reason why I'm stuck), but I have spent 2 days trying to find an answer for my problem with no luck whatsoever.
Here's the deal: I have downloaded the python module for Stanford NER, because I need to extract entities from text. In the readme file there was a suggestion on how it should be used, which was the following:

```
import ner

tagger = ner.HttpNER(host = 'localhost', port = 8080)
tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
```

The problem is that I have little (almost zero) experience with python and when executing it i get the following error message:
[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I don't know why I get this message, since port 8080 is not used or blocked. I have even tried to disable the firewall and the antivirus, but nothing changed.

I assume my question is kind of a newbie question, but I have searched for almost two days to figure out what is wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It means nothing is listening on port 8080 on localhost.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I knew that this was the case, but I forgot to mention that I already have a server listening on port 8080. That is why I'm concerned.

Comment: And itis listening on localhost? Did you confirm that it's listening e.g. using netstat`

Comment: Yes it is listening to port 8080. When tying netstat -aon the following result appears, among others:

TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0       LISTENING   5924

This PID is associated with Apache.